# We need advice for a server software implementation with Java NIO

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, nio

I'm trying to calculate the load on a server I have to build.

I need to create a server witch have one million users registered in an SQL database. During a week each user will approximately connect 3-4 times. Each time a user will up and download 1-30 MB data, and it will take maybe 1-2 minutes.

When an upload is complete it will be deleted within minutes. 
(Update text removed error in calculations)

I know how to make and query an SQL database but what to consider in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Netty for a similar scenario. It is just working!

Here is a **starting point** for using netty:

```
public class TCPListener {
    private static ServerBootstrap bootstrap;

    public static void run(){
        bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                TCPListnerHandler handler = new MyHandler();
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
                pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);

                return pipeline;
            }
        });

        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));  //port number is 9999
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run();
    }
}
```

and MyHandler class:

```
public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(
        ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {


        try {
            String remoteAddress = e.getRemoteAddress().toString();
            ChannelBuffer buffer= (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
            //Now the buffer contains byte stream from client.

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] output; //suppose output is a filled byte array
        ChannelBuffer writebuffer = ChannelBuffers.buffer(output.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            writebuffer.writeByte(output[i]);
        }


        e.getChannel().write(writebuffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        e.getChannel().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Farshid Zaker Thanks, where do i start to learn Netty except the obvious Apache site. I know there are different brands of Netty right?
Easy beginner reading..Books?

Comment: @Farshid Zake thanks I see it looks quite easy. I have thoughts about the NIO mechanism. If all my users never interact with each other. Ans only need filesystem, Sql access. No singletons or static. What type of NIO type of approach should i use?

Comment: @Farshid Zake What about if i want encryption. Encrypted login and all files sent/received to be encrypted. Guess i can make the sender encrypt and compress the files. But the sql login part, is there some Netty library for that?

Comment: I have implemented encryption in both sides (client and server). I don't know if this approach works for you. Any way, I have implemented the encryption mechanisms outside of Netty.

Comment: @Farshid Zaker That sound good. you say you use Netty for a similar scenario. Can you elaborate please. How many connections on average do you have? I have been wanted to ask you specific about the Netty.
(did not jet read up on Netty) If everything is running on one thread. How can each connected user do the work?

Comment: Sometimes nobody is connected! And sometimes about 100 devices (yes, devices not users!) are connected. It is going to increase next month to several hundreds. In test situation, it supports 1000 concurrent connections.
By the way, who says everything is running on a single thread?

Answer (score 5):

What you want exactly is [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). It's an API written in NIO and provides another event driven model instead of the classic thread model.
It doesn't use a thread per request, but it put the requests in a queue. With this tool you can make up to 250,000 requests per second.

Comment: Will second Netty: quite reasonable. A bit more complex than one would expect, but full featured.

Comment: What is "Will second Netty:"? NETTY2?

Comment: +1 I love Netty and, IMHO, is **much** easier and more powerful than Java sockets and Java NIO.

Comment: @Erik : Excuse me where is it mentioned ?

Comment: @Erik, Definition:
sec·ond /'sekənd/
Verb: Formally support or endorse (a nomination or resolution or its proposer) as a necessary preliminary to adoption or further discussion.

Answer (score 4):

> At first I was thinking this many
>   users would require a non-blocking
>   solution but my calculations show that
>   I dont, [am I] right?

On modern operating systems and hardware, [thread-per-connection is faster than non-blocking](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-io-faster-than-nio-old-is-new-again/) I/O, at least unless the number of connections reaches truely extreme levels. However, for writing the data to disk, NIO (channels and buffers) may help, because it can use [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) and avoid copy operations.

But overall, I also think network bandwidth and storage are your main concerns in this application.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt Good point thanks. I looks like Netty is the way to go. Thankfully I have no limitations when it comes to hardware and bandwidth. I have two month to produce the server. DO you have any suggestion in Books, example or code samples

Comment: @Erik: actually my point is that there is no reason to complicate your design by using netty. Using classic threaded IO should be fine.

Comment: @Michael Borgward I was thinking NIO is better since the only purpose is to let users save/load files from HDD. No calculations no waiting. Simply in and out delivering or getting a file. Really so you think i can use the David Flanagan´s (link) approacher if i just make sure i have like 4 server computers using SSD disks? LoadBalansing computers

Comment: @Erik: your threads will have quite a lot of work to do just handling all that data. And I'd definitely use an established server component like Tomcat rather than example code from a book.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt Can you elaborate on that Tomcat. Some people say i can use simple java threading and some say Netty. How does Tomcat work compared to the other?

Comment: @Erik: Tomcat is a server based on the thread-per-connection model. The advantage over building your own server from scratch is that it's mature, tested and tuned code based on widely-used standards so that you can use third-party components e.g. for security. The advantage over Netty is that it's a simpler programming model that more developers are familiar with (nearly every Java developer has experience with Servlets). And, as I said, it will probably perform better as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is Tomcat for HTTP only?

Comment: @Erik: it can speak other protocols via the Connector API, but I think they have to be pretty similar to HTTP for this to work well. In any case, HTTP is pretty well-suited for uploading large data if you use it correctly (i.e. use headers to allow uploads to be resumed).

Comment: @Michael, I am not quite sure about all those benchmarks, if one doesn't use Direct buffers (heavily) w/ NIO, there is no point to run the trouble. Btw, tomcat has nio as well and it even few bugs/design flaw works ok, it doesn't necessary uses thread per connection.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to remember is that most users do not access a system evenly in every hour of every day of the week. Your system need to perform correctly during the busiest hour of the week.

Say the busiest hour of the week, 1/50 of all uploads are made. In the busiest hour each upload could be 30 MB, a total of 1.8 TB. This means you need to have an Internet upload bandwidth to support this. 1.8 TB/hour * 8 bits/byte / 60 min/hour / 60 sec/min = 4 Gbit/s Internet connection.

If for example, you have only a 1 Gbit/s connection, this will limit access to your server.

The other thing to consider is your retention time for these uploads.  If each upload is 15 MB on average, you will be getting 157 TB per week or 8.2 PB (8200 TB) per year. You may need a significant amount of storage to retain this.

Once you have spend a significant amount of money on Internet connectivity and disk, the cost of buying a couple of servers is minor. You could use Apache MIMA, however a single server with a 10 Gbit/s connection can support 1 GB easily using any software you care to chose.

A single PC/server/labtop can handle 1,000 I/O threads so 300-600 is not a lot.

The problem will not be in the software but in the network/hardware you chose.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lawrey. I edited my questions for more details. My customers are world width but Europa and USA might give me peeks in queries since they have better data plan bandwidth. I have contract with a Server Hall providing all the computers and can expand quickly.

Comment: @Erik, you might find that disk IO is a issue.  50 MB/second is relatively easy, but 125 MB/s (for is harder 1 Gb) and 500 MB/s (for 4 Gb upload) will require multiple back end data storage systems.

Comment: If you read and write 150 TB per month that is 300 TB total. Amazon would charge about $30K/month for this IO rate. Can these files be compressed because if they can this could really help reduce costs?

Comment: @  Peter Lawrey Thanks i have relayed your consideration to my Server provider, lets see what they say about this. I live in Sweden btw. Thanks for your point